# how to prove that (a) = (b) equivalent to a = bc and c is reversible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, ring-theory

i did a try and i want to check my solution. the initial question said tha a and b are part of a ring A.

(a) , (b) represent an ideals in the ring A.

my answer was that i proceed by using a proof from both sides.
first i put that c is reversible and (a) is included in (b)

```
     -that means that we might have d in A so cd = 1
     -and if (a) is in (b) that give us a is also in (b)
```

so from the question we have that a = bc then ad = b
also b is inluded in (a) and by definition of the ideals (b) is included in (a).

this is was my guess for the first part, but for the second part '(a) = (b) implies that c is reversible' i dont have a good answer.
thanks anyway.

Comment: "Irreversible?" Did you mean invertible? Because irreversible doesn't mean anything when talking elements of a ring, and if it did, it would mean the opposite of irreversible, because English word prefix "ir-" means "not."

Comment: It's certainly true if $A$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: yes that what i meant, because i'm from France and the element that can be multiplied by another element and give the unite we called it like that

Comment: yes A has no 0 devisors

Comment: I doubt you call it anything equivalent to "irreversible." You might call it "reversible."

Comment: Put all the details in your question, not in comments. Update your question and let us know what you've tried, what you've been taught so far, etc, or the question will remain closed an nobody can answer it.

Comment: so do you have any idea how can i prove this statement

Comment: ok i'll update the question

Comment: Yes, I do, but I'm not here to do your homework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have determined that $a\in (b)\implies a=bc$ and $b\in (a)\implies b=ad$ for some $c,d$ in the ring.

This gives us that $a=bc=(ad)c=a(dc)\implies a(1-dc)=0$.

Likewise, we have that $b=ad=(bc)d=b(cd)\implies b(1-cd)=0$

If the ring has no zero divisors and neither $a$ nor $b$ are zero, what can you say about the relationship between $c$ and $d$?

Comment: yes, understand what are you saying :

Comment: if we have a(1- dc) = 0 and a(1-cd) = 0 and the ring has no zero divisors . that mean that 1-cd = 0 and 1-dc = 0 . in conclusion cd = dc = 1 and c is reversible. thanks for the contribution.